# Can I install a OSC mobile theme to CRE Loaded v6.1?

Tags: php, mobile, oscommerce

I have a question about OSCommerce and storefronts based on it. I'm running a heavily modified [CRE Loaded](http://www.loadedcommerce.com/index.php) v6.1 storefront on my site.

My first question is: on which OSC version is this built?

Also, I want to install an [OSC mobile theme](http://www.css-oscommerce.com/mobile-oscommerce/) that is available for another customization of OSCommerce named "[OSC to CSS v2](http://www.css-oscommerce.com/osc-to-css-v2/)". Will this theme be compatible with CRE Loaded 6.1? What can I do to make sure that this will work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are incompatible.  CSS osCommerce is an entirely different fork of osCommerce than CRE Loaded.

Answer (score 1):

This release was the first one released under my management.  Like all CRE Loaded 6.x releases it is based on osCommerce 2.2 MS2.

CRE Loaded incorporates the BTS template system - and any modification of this nature would need to be adapted to that system.   6.1A is rather old, and you are probably overdue for a security update.

Comment: So you are saying that the files are or might be incompatible?